# Spring Server Generator | Controller interface naming | OpenApi 3.0.2

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am trying to workout a generated server side Springboot MVC code for a OpenApi 3.0.2 specification.

This is how one of the `paths' look like :-

```
paths:
  /v1/time/integrations/{some-path-variable}/some-action:
    get:
      summary: Summary
      description: How to change the generated Api/Controller class name?
      operationId: methodName
      tags:
        - inventory
      parameters:
        - name: Authorization
      other details....
```

The server side code get generated using the Maven plugin which is configured as :-

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>               
    <version>4.1.0</version>           

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/open-api/myapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                <library>spring-boot</library>
                <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-openapi/spring</output>
                <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                <addCompileSourceRoot>true</addCompileSourceRoot>
                <artifactVersion>${project.version}</artifactVersion>
                <groupId>com.company.division</groupId>
                <artifactId>myapi-api</artifactId>
                <generateApiTests>true</generateApiTests>
                <modelPackage>com.company.division.myapi.generated.model</modelPackage>
                <apiPackage>com.company.division.myapi.generated.api</apiPackage>
                <supportingFilesToGenerate>ApiUtil.java</supportingFilesToGenerate>
          <configOptions>
            <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
          </configOptions>
          <modelNameSuffix>Dto</modelNameSuffix><!-- To prevent class name conflicts with the JPA entities -->
        </configuration>
            </configuration>

        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Problem

All the controllers are inside V1api file I want to skip /v1/ and use "time" from path as controller class. This way all the paths which have "time" will come under time rest controller. Is there any way I can achieve that? I cannot remove v1 as I have v2 api as well with same name and swagger docket is grouping that in different spec.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any solution allowing to tamper with names generated from `path` scalar. However, you can control generated class names with `tags`.

To achieve that, you have to set `useTags` configOption in your openapi-generator execution definition:

```
<configuration>
    <configOptions>
        <useTags>true</useTags>
    </configOptions>
</configuration>
```

Your API paths will be grouped by the first `tags` value from your yaml (in your case: *inventory*) and put into corresponding generated API classes (with name prefixed also according to first `tags` element, in your case i.e. *InventoryApi* and *InventoryApiController*). Hence to get *Time** names, you would have to adjust `tags` in your yaml.
And to separate v1 and v2 API, tags should be like "time-v1" and "time-v2", to generate separate API classes for each tag.